# Why is there extra space at the bottom of my two column website?

Tags: html, css

There is empty space at the bottom of my site, showing just the background image. If I set the height of .content to auto or 100%, that makes things even worse and destroys the site. How can I get rid of this empty space while still preserving the white box holding all my content?

http://www.michaelaoun.com/noursite.html

Link to the html file: https://www.mediafire.com/?l435v31v56du9ms

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS directly in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this. Is it acceptable to post the entire thing? It's fairly long.

Comment: for future regerence: you should post the minimal code that can make us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll do that going forward. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `overflow:auto` CSS style to your `#mainContent` div so it expands to the floating content inside of it.